# В каком слове есть сочетание букв нщ

Tags: словообразование

В каком слове есть сочетание букв нща

Comment: Для этого есть словари.

Comment: Уточните, какое именно сочетание вам требуется. Сочетание НЩ не редкое для русского - на стыке корня и суффикса (погонщик, бетонщик), а вот НЩА - найти не удалось.

Comment: Конщавель (неформальное сокращение от "конский щавель") - 1 раз встретилось в форуме: http://www.forumnz.org/vbul/showthread.php?1736-%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%B4!-%D0%92%D1%81%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B4!-%29%29%29/page9

Answer (score 1):

Проверила в словаре в Linuxе.

> aspell dump master ru | grep нща

(поиск слов, включающих *нща*)
не дает ни одного слова,
а

> aspell dump master ru | grep нщ

(поиск слов, включающих *нщ*)
дает кучу слов, оканчивающихся на *-нщик, -нщица, -нщина*.

Comment: Какой интересный способ! +1 !!

Answer (score 0):

Вот самое начало списка
авиаугонщик, -а
авиационщик, -а
автогенщик, -а
автогонщик, -а
автоугонщик, -а
алюминщик, -а
антеннщик, -а
атаманщина, -ы
бакенщик, -а
балаганщик, -а
http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=*%D0%BD%D1%89*&all=x
Дальше можете искать по первым буквам.

На *-нща-* немарсианских слов не найдено.

Answer (score -1):

Ребёнок зачем-то неправильно продублировал свой вопрос с опечаткой, - не интересует его ***конщавель***, а вовсе даже наоборот: гуглить не умеет, про словари не слышал...

На тебе:

1. атаманщина
2. баллонщик
3. вагранщик
4. временщик
5. гарпунщик
6. гетманщина
7. гребенщик
8. гребенщиковые
9. гребенщиковый
10. жестянщик
11. знаменщик
12. карманщик
13. картонщик
14. картонщица
15. кессонщик
16. корзинщик
17. корзинщица
18. майданщик
19. мартенщик
20. масленщик
21. обыденщина
22. оловянщик
23. патронщик
24. подгонщик
25. подменщик
26. понтонщик
27. прогонщик
28. пружинщица
29. расценщик
30. сбитенщик
31. славянщина
32. старинщик
33. турбинщик
34. форсунщик
35. форсунщица
36. фургонщик
37. фурманщик
38. чайханщик
39. шаблонщик
40. шарманщик

Подборка срисована [отсель](http://bezbukv.ru/mask/*****%D0%BD%D1%89$).

1. оконщик
2. оценщик
3. сгонщик
4. сканщик
5. сменщик
6. угонщик

[Источник](http://bezbukv.ru/mask/***%D0%BD%D1%89**)

Не убирала однокоренные, потому что: а цифирь куда?

От себя: денщик, гонщик.

Ой, да их, готовеньких, [тьма тьмущая](http://bezbukv.ru/mask/$%D0%BD%D1%89**) и без словарей:

1. автогенщик
2. бакенщик
3. балаганщик
4. баллонщик
5. банщик
6. барабанщик
7. басонщик
8. бетонщик
9. былинщик
10. бюллетенщик
11. вагонщик
12. вагранщик
13. велогонщик
14. веретенщик
15. волынщик
16. временщик
17. выгонщик
18. гарпунщик
19. гонщик
20. гребенщик
21. денщик
22. деревянщик
23. доменщик
24. духанщик
25. желонщик
26. жестянщик
27. загонщик
28. затонщик
29. зачинщик
30. зеленщик
31. знаменщик
32. изменщик
33. икрянщик
34. каменщик
35. караванщик
36. карманщик
37. картонщик
38. керосинщик
39. кессонщик
40. коконщик
41. корзинщик
42. кормленщик
43. латынщик
44. магазинщик
45. майданщик
46. макаронщик
47. манекенщик
48. мартенщик
49. масленщик
50. миллионщик
51. мороженщик
52. мотогонщик
53. начинщик
54. обгонщик
55. обезьянщик
56. обманщик
57. обменщик
58. оконщик
59. оловянщик
60. органщик
61. отгонщик
62. оценщик
63. патронщик
64. перегонщик
65. повременщик
66. погонщик
67. подгонщик
68. поденщик
69. подкаменщик
70. подменщик
71. половинщик
72. понтонщик
73. починщик
74. прогонщик
75. расценщик
76. расчеканщик
77. резинщик
78. ременщик
79. самогонщик
80. сбитенщик
81. сгонщик
82. сканщик
83. скотопрогонщик
84. сменщик
85. смологонщик
86. старинщик
87. стерженщик
88. струнщик
89. суконщик
90. табунщик
91. турбинщик
92. тюленщик
93. угонщик
94. фасонщик
95. фельетонщик
96. филигранщик
97. форсунщик
98. фортепьянщик
99. фуганщик
100. фургонщик
101. фурманщик
102. чайханщик
103. чеканщик
104. чемоданщик
105. шаблонщик
106. шарманщик
107. щебенщик
108. щетинщик

     ---

В общем,

***Иветта, Лизетта, Мюзетта, Жанетта, Жоржетта,
Колетта, Полетта, Кларетта, Флоретта, ах! - Мариетта,***

гуглить надо ***Слова, содержащие в середине сочетание букв НЩ***.

Comment: Не надо гуглить. Надо просто уметь пользоваться словарем.